# how to sum multiple array textbox

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, ms-access, textbox

This is my code for an array textbox . I want to show the addition of array textbox boxpoamount in txttotalamount. but instead of adding each of the value of boxpoamount. the codes only multiply the last textbox of poamount to the number of how many the boxpoamount.

```
 Dim newpoamountbox As New List(Of TextBox)


 Private Sub controlall(ByVal controlcount As Integer)

  Dim boxpoamount As TextBox

  For i As Integer = 1 To controlcount
            boxpoamount = New TextBox
            boxpoamount.Size = New Drawing.Size(100, 20)
            boxpoamount.Location = New Drawing.Point(1013, 542 + 58 * (i - 1))
            newpoamountbox.Add(boxpoamount)
            Me.Controls.Add(boxpoamount)
        Next

       Private Sub boxunitpricecom(ByRef boxpoqty As TextBox, ByRef boxpounitprice As TextBox, ByRef boxpoamount As TextBox)
            'MessageBox.Show("right")

            Dim var1 As String
            Dim var2 As String
            Dim var3 As String
            'Dim var4 As String
            'Dim amount As String

            Try

                var1 = Val(boxpoqty.Text)
                var2 = Val(boxpounitprice.Text)
                var3 = var1 * var2
                boxpoamount.Text = var3



                Dim txt As TextBox
                Dim Sum As Integer
                Dim controlall As Integer = Val(txtpoitemno.Text)
                For I = 1 To controlall
                    txt = CType(Me.Controls(boxpoamount.Text + I.ToString()), TextBox)
                    Sum = Sum + Double.Parse(boxpoamount.Text)

                Next I
                txttotalamount.Text = Sum.ToString()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Finally
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Close()

            End Try

        End Sub
```

Comment: check this line:

     txt = CType(Me.Controls(boxpoamount.Text + I.ToString()), TextBox)

what are you doing with txt?

Comment: What are the instance names of the textboxes you want to check? Do you have their instances?

Comment: it should came from boxpoamount and show the total in txttotalamount

Comment: perhaps, you should do `boxpoamount.Name = "mytb" + i` to help yourself finding the instance of the textboxes later... ah, I see, they are in the list. Then you are good. :)

Comment: what? and where should i put the boxpoamount.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Dim txt As TextBox
Dim Sum As Integer
Dim controlall As Integer = Val(txtpoitemno.Text)
For I = 1 To controlall
    txt = CType(Me.Controls(boxpoamount.Text + I.ToString()), TextBox)
    Sum = Sum + Double.Parse(boxpoamount.Text)
Next I
```

Into looping for your `List`

```
Dim Sum As Integer = 0
Dim Val As Integer = 0
For Each tb As TextBox In newpoamountbox
    If Integer.TryParse(tb.Text, Val) Then
        Sum += Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text)
    End If
Next
```

Then assign the `Sum` to the text box showing the result... (use `TryParse` just to be safe)